# Get List of Messages from POP3 Mail Server

Tags: .net

i need to get the list of messages (inbox) from pop3 mail server then save them into a folder.
i'm using .net framework 3.5.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some Googling turn up [this](http://www.harryfino.com/2009/07/23/the-elusive-ssl-pop3-client-in-c/):

Basically:

- The framework has no POP client class
- Make your own (or copy it from the link)
- Use it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) Class to connect and then you just send the correct commands as specified in the RFC: [RFC 1939 - Post Office Protocol - Version 3](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html)

Specifically, look at the `LIST` and `RETR` commands.

You can find some tutorials/articles if you search on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/).

However, if the messages have attachments or similar, it'll be a bit more complicated since you'll then also have to look into how to decode them, I'd suggest that you start with the wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) in that case and then there's some tutorials for this as well on CodeProject.